# Limit on Y-Axis Value in Chart

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-chart

This may not be an option currently for the Kendo Charts, however, I want to set a limit on the max value displayed on the chart. The chart I am displaying gives the user the option to select fixed y-axis at 100% or auto y-axis. The information being displayed is CPU usage so it's absolute maximum value is 100%.

**The problem:** I have found that if I use auto y-axis (don't provide a max y-value) then when the data hits 100% the chart will display up to 120% because of the 20% step size.

**My current fix:** I check the max value in the returned data during the chart render event. If the max value is >= 80% then I set the y-axis max to 100% so it doesn't display 120%. Then I redraw the chart.

Is there a better way to do this so I don't  have to redraw the chart? I didn't have this problem with other charting libraries.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up moving the code to update the max y-value from onRender to onDataBound. This way still feels kind of "hacky", but it ended up causing only one chart render event instead of two.

Answer (score 1):

Is [valueAxis.max](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#configuration-valueAxis.max) setting that you need ?